# SignalR IIS With React - "Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled."

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, signalr

I am developing a .Net Core (3.1) web application hosted with IIS 10. When I am trying to use SignalR on localhost, I am able to connect totally fine and receive messages from the backend, but after I publish it to IIS, I get the error: "Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled." In the client logs on Chrome's console, I get the message: "Information: SSE connected to [http://myserver.com/MyApplication/output"](http://myserver.com/MyApplication/output%22) before I get the error described above (which you would think means that I connected successfully)...

I have seen other posts where people have suggested that I have to enable webSockets on IIS, and I have already checked the my site has this enabled.

I have also seen people suggest to try using the longPolling argument in the withUrl function when creating the connection, and this has not helped either.

I have also added SignalR Event Log Trace Listeners to my web.config file, and the only warning I get that might be related to this issue is that I get a warning from the .NET runtime that reads "Failed to determine the https port for redirect." I am not sure what this means or if it would be related to SignalR, but as this also appears to deal with Middleware, it might be significant.

One thing that I thought might be related is that my site is just one of multiple hosted on this server, so that when I am running locally, I can use the following to connect to SignalR:

`hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/output").build();`

But because of the way this site is deployed on my server, I have to use this:

`hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/MyApplication/output").build();`

when I deploy the site or else I get a 404 error...

Would there be any issue there? I noticed when inspecting the network requests that on localhost, the URL to connect with the socket is "wss://localhost:44315/output?id=..." and I get the "Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols", but after I deploy, the url that is used is "http://myserver.com/MyApplication/output?id=..." and I get a "200 OK" just before receiving the error described at the top. Why does wss get used on localhost but http is requested from my client when I deploy?

Comment: About generally like this kind of network problem, data transmission is interrupted, I suggest you use some tools like fiddler to capture network data packets and traffic packets. After obtaining these packages, analyze the data in them to find out the point and cause of the interruption.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FINALLY discovered the issue after days of debugging... The reason I was getting a "101" response on localhost and not when published is because 101 is basically the server (IIS in my case) saying "I support web sockets". I realized that because I wasn't getting this when published, web sockets were probably not enabled in IIS. It was weird, however, because I went into IIS manager and it said that web sockets *were* enabled, but after much more research, I found that you also have to go into "Server Manager" and enable it as well (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support and follow step by step instructions). I did not realize both were required.